# HTC desire 816 insufficient space error

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have an htc desire 816 that I just recently bought and it was fine at first but it stared giving me the error message that there was "insufficient space on the device" when I tried to download any app. I went and bought myself an SD card but even with the SD card in it, the phone is still giving me this error message. Any ideas why or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Android 4.4 [does not support installing apps to SD Card](http://www.androidcentral.com/kitkat-sdcard-changes).
Your best bet is to [root your phone](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2775801), then [install an app](http://www.droidviews.com/restore-write-capability-to-external-sd-card-on-kitkat-manually/) that will enable you write to the SD Card.
Those steps will get you as far as writing to the SD Card. I don't have a device that I can test this on, but [these steps](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-apps-onto-your-SD-Card-No-Root/?ALLSTEPS) look like they might work for having apps install to the SD card by default. Let me know if you have any luck!